How to determine a quadratic surface is an ellipsoid?
There is a quadratic function:
$$
f(x,y,z)=Ax^2+By^2+Cz^2+Dxy+Eyz+Fxz+Gx+Hy+Iz+K=0.
$$
I want to determine whether this quadratic surface is an ellipsoid. I think this can be solved by check the $4\times 4$ matrix Q which can represented that $f(x,y,z)$ as $X^TQX$ where $ X = [x,y,z,1] $. Can anyone help me?
Can I just check the matrix :
$$W=
\begin{pmatrix}
A &\frac{D}{2} & \frac{F}{2}\\
\frac{D}{2} &B & \frac{E}{2}\\
\frac{F}{2}&\frac{E}{2}&C
\end {pmatrix},\quad V=
\begin{pmatrix}
A &\frac{D}{2} & \frac{F}{2} & \frac{G}{2}\\
\frac{D}{2} & B & \frac{E}{2} & \frac{H}{2}\\
\frac{F}{2} & \frac{E}{2} & C & \frac{I}{2}\\
\frac{G}{2}&\frac{H}{2}&\frac{I}{2}&J
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If $W$ is positive and the matrix $det(V)\neq0$ , then the quadratic surface is ellipsoid?

first find the 3 by 3 Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives. This needs to be positive definite. Next, you need to confirm that the real solution set is not empty and is more than a single point. This amounts to finding the minimum point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ of your function   where the gradient is the zero vector. There is more

Meanwhile, I imagine there is a 4 by 4 method. I think of it as homogenizing with a new variable $w,$  now the last four terms become $Gxw + Hyw + Izw +Kw^2$  Now you have a 4 by 4 Hessian matrix to play with.

Thank for your suggestion, i have another ideal , can you help me?

I'm afraid your comment about the constants being positive is wrong as stated. If you    have 2 dimensional $x^2 + y^2 + 6x + 10y +34 = 0$  you have a single point, it is $(x+3)^2 + (y+5)^2 = 0$  If you were given $x^2 + y^2 + 6x + 10y +35 = 0$  it would be the empty set  since $(x+3)^2 + (y+5)^2  + 1= 0$  has no points with $x,y$ real. This shows my comment about the gradient as well as the need for completing the squares  to write this around the minimum point. Suggest you experiment with 2 dimensional conics for a while. Try to find out if $2x^2 + xy + 3 y^2 + 7x +9y + 13 = 0$  has points.

@Will I have a new idea such that ensure the ellipsoid will not degenerate, is this idea true?

You need to find the eigenvalues of matrix $W$.  For more details, see the link here.
